# Are sets of incommensurable real numbers all denumerable?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Definition of *incommensurability*:

- Supposing $a,b \in \mathbb{R}^*$, $a,b$ are called incommensurable if and only if $\frac{a}{b}\notin\mathbb{Q}$.

---

From the lectures of KAM theory concerning the small divisor problem, I wonder:

1. Is it possible to construct a *non denumerable* subset $S$ of $\mathbb{R}^\ast$ such that $\forall \left(a,b\right) \in S^2, a,b $ incommensurable?
2. Same question without admitting the *Axiom of Choice*.

The problem is inspired by the fact that every [integrable Hamiltonian system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrable_system#Hamiltonian_systems_and_Liouville_integrability) of $N$ degrees of freedom in classical mechanics, shall have a $N$-periodic motion. In the case which two fundamental frequencies of such system are commensurable (called the [degeneracy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Action-angle_coordinates#Degeneracy)), there will exist additional physical conserved quantities. So it would be interesting to see if one's able or not to construct a non denumerable set of incommensurable real frequencies, for which is the necessary condition of the existence of a classical integrable system with non denumerable degrees of freedom. (Normally the classical smooth fields in finite dimensions are systems with only denumerable degrees of freedom)

Comment: Don't you mean $\frac ab\notin\mathbb Q$ in the definition?

Comment: You've got it backwards. To say that $a,b$ are ***commensurable*** means that $a/b \in \mathbb Q$, and to say they are ***incommensurable*** means that $a/b \not\in\mathbb Q$. Besides that, posts consisting of bare problem statements [without any context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#9960) can easily attract close votes on this site.

Comment: Thank you, Hagen and Lee, for pointing this error out, and for informing me the good manner of posting questions in this community. I edited the post.

Comment: See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/23202/explicit-big-linearly-independent-sets for explicit uncountable subsets with a stronger property.

Comment: This question often arises in set theory when one considers the real numbers as a vector space over the rationals.  There is a “Hamel basis” $H$ of reals with the property that each real $r$ has a _unique_ representation as a _finite_ sum $r = \sum q_ih_i$ where the $q_i$ are rational and $h_i\in H$. Such a basis always has cardinality ${\mathfrak c} = |\Bbb R|$.  [(See for example)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4242764/25554). However, the existence of the Hamel basis is equivalent to the axiom of choice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given some $x \in \mathbb{R}$, let $[x]$ denote the *equivalence class of $x$*, which is defined to be
$$ [x] = \{ y \in \mathbb{R} : x/y \in \mathbb{Q} \}. $$
Note $[x]$ is precisely the set of real numbers numbers which are commensurable with $x$.  Note, also, that $[x]$ is countable:  the function
$$ \mathbb{Q} \to [x] : q \mapsto qx$$
is bijective, and the rationals are countable.

The set of real numbers can be written as the union of all of these equivalence clases.  Via the axiom of choice, choose a representative from each one of these equivalence classes, and let $S$ denote the set of these chosen representatives.  Then
$$ \mathbb{R} = \bigcup_{x\in S} [x]. $$
Each equivalence class $[x]$ is countable, and so $\mathbb{R}$ has been expressed as a union of sets, each of which is countable.  But $\mathbb{R}$ is uncountable, so there must be uncountably many sets in that union.  Therefore $S$ is uncountable.

Note that this argument *does* rely on the axiom of choice, and I do not see any way of "constructing" such an $S$ without reliance on it (which does not mean that no such method exists, I just don't see any "obvious" way to get around the axiom of choice).

Comment: Since it is consistent with ZF that the real numbers is a countable union of sets with 2 elements each, I don't think you can avoid AC.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Yeah, that is my intuition, but I lack the formal knowledge / experience / training to feel confident about getting the details right.  I live in a world where the AoC is taken for granted.

Comment: +1, just beware to restrict everywhere to *nonzero* real numbers. Note for the OP: this answer essentially says that the [projective space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_space#Definition) (= set of one-dimensional subspaces) of the $\Bbb Q$-vector space $\Bbb R$ is uncountable.

Comment: You *can* avoid AC: follow [this link](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/23202), given yesterday in [@EricWofsey's comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4800400/timeline#comment_10213986).

Comment: @Arturo: It is consistent that the reals are a countable union of countable sets. Yes. But every countable union of finite sets of reals is countable, so not equal to the whole set. The reason is simple: since the reals are linearly ordered we can uniformly enumerate all the finite subsets.